# Dell R210 eSata not recognizing Sata Drive

Tags: windows-server-2008, dell, sata, drive, esata

We have a Dell R210 with an external Sata connection.

When connecting the Sata drive through the eSata connection, the server does not recognize the additional drive.

What we have tried:

- Verified that the drive was turned on when booting the server
- Verified eSata was set to Automatic in BIOS (the other option of disabled)
- Verified that it is in AHCI mode and not RAID in the bios
- Verified that plugins were secure and that power was getting to the drive
- Verified that it does not appear in Disk Manager or Device Manager, Did a manual rescan with device manager after each of the aforementioned steps.

We do not have another cable to test with handy. I have been walking an end user through as the site is about a 1,000 miles away from the office.

Any input for why this drive is not connecting would be helpful.

EDIT: The drive is getting power from the casing that came with it. We have made sure that it is powered on. We also tried having it powered on before booting into windows.

Comment: eSATA does not provide power. Are you providing power to the drive in some other way?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not mentioning that, it is getting power from the drive casing.

Comment: I am reasonably sure that you have tested this, but: Does the drive work in another computer? (Read: are you sure the drive itself it not broken).

Comment: The sad thing is, is that my boss says he tested it but I am not 100% if we have. There is no other machine to test it against onsite. Which is a GREAT disadvantage and will make this whole ordeal more difficult than it should be but these are the cards that have been dealt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was a Hardware issue with the eSata cable. We should have tested it more thoroughly.

Thank you all for your input. Hate to answer my own question but that is what we got.

Again, thank you serverfault community.